# Printf error with optional arguments

Tags: ocaml

Suppose I write this function :

```
let f ?(x=0) fmt y = Format.fprintf fmt "%d" (x+y)
```

Its type is : `?x:int -> Format.formatter -> int -> unit`

I can call it specifying `x` or not.

Now, let's call it like this :

```
let () = Format.printf "%a@." f 0
```

I have this error :

```
Error: This expression has type ?x:int -> Format.formatter -> int -> unit
       but an expression was expected of type Format.formatter -> 'a -> unit
```

Well, I don't get why this would be a problem. The argument is optional, if I don't put it it should be ok, no ? *(writing* `Format.printf "%a" (f ~x:0) 0` *works, obviously, but what's the point in having optional argument?)*

I mean, if I declare my function like this :

```
let f ?(x=0) () fmt y = Format.fprintf fmt "%d" (x+y)
```

Its type will be : `?x:int -> () -> Format.formatter -> int -> unit` and calling `Format.printf "%a@." (f ()) 0` will work. So I guess there's a problem with an optional argument not being able to be the last argument of a function but it is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue stems from the very flexible type of `printf`: `('a, Format.formatter, unit) format -> 'a`. By the time, the typechecker deduced that the expected type of `f` was `Format.formatter -> int -> unit`, it was too late to apply the optional argument. In this case, even helping the typechecker a little can solve the issue (but breaks principality)

```
let pf fmt f = Format.printf fmt f
let () = pf "%a@." f 0 (* works *)
```

Note that this is quite general issue, higher-order functions have some difficulties to handle function arguments with labelled or optional arguments.

Comment: What I don't understand is why adding the `()` parameter makes it work, then.

Comment: With an `()` argument, the typechecker can deduce that the optional argument was omitted when checking `f ()`, the inference is therefore much more local; whereas in the `printf` application the elimination of the optional argument relies on the type information flowing from the application context.